# Delete memory in inheritance

Tags: c++

I have code below, it always has memory leak please help me.

Thanks,
Ankata

---

```
 class ABCD
{
public:
    ABCD(void);
    ~ABCD(void);

    CString tem1;
    CString tem2;
};

class CDE :
    public ABCD
{
public:
    CDE(void);
    ~CDE(void);
    CString tem;
};

void main()
{
        CList<ABCD*> m;
        CDE *a = new CDE();

        a->tem1 = "AAA";
        a->tem2 ="BBB";
        a->tem ="CCC";

        m.AddTail(a);

        ABCD *b = m.GetTail();
        delete b;   
}
```

Comment: What does 'it always has memory' mean? Also, you have not shown the definitions for your classes, only the declarations.

Comment: I don't understand what "it always has memory" means.  Please clarify this question.  There's a lot wrong with this code, and it's not all there, so hard to make any concrete suggestions.

Comment: Is the CString in CDE (tem) not getting freed? You would need a virtual destructor on the ABCD and CDE class. In the last two lines of main the GetTail() and delete is going to call ABCD destructor the not the CDE destructor. Making the destructors virtual will fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your destructor for class ABCD is not virtual so by casting the pointer to base class type, it will not call the destructor of the derived one thus not freeing memory allocated in CDE.

Comment: Mark the question answered then ;)

Comment: Well, the OP can only accept an answer after 15 minutes. Be patient ;)

Answer (score 2):

The destructor for `ABCD` needs to be `virtual`.

Answer (score 1):

Your ABCD destructor should be virtual for one, if you're going to use the base class pointer to delete the class

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with this code, and we don't have definitions, so hard to know what's specifically wrong.

1. When using inheritance, unless you know what you are doing, make destructors virtual.  In your specific case, the ABCD destructor will be called, not the CDE one as it should
2. Don't delete b unless you are also removing it from m.  If not, m contains a dangling pointer